# Syntenic gene browser

Tags: sequence-annotation, genome-browser

I found that there is a Syntenic gene browser at [GEvo](https://genomevolution.org/wiki/index.php/Syntenic_gene_sets). Do anyone know where could I find a similar browser for a local installation?

Answer (score 1):

The UCSC genome browser supports local mirrors. You could make a local mirror that has the "TransMap Alignments" cross-species gene track. From the [track description page](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTrackUi?hgsid=660022369_AUzllaH1GkM6HAQrM1t7y25Cdpme&c=chr5&g=transMapV4):

> These tracks contain cDNA and gene alignments produced by the TransMap cross-species alignment algorithm from other vertebrate species in the UCSC Genome Browser. For closer evolutionary distances, the alignments are created using syntenically filtered LASTZ or BLASTZ alignment chains, resulting in a prediction of the orthologous genes in human. For more distant organisms, reciprocal best alignments are used.

They provide a helpful tutorial on setting up a local installation [here](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/help/mirror.html).